# how to active bluetooth and wifi of mt7921 in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04, mediatek

I have mt7921 of asus tuf fx506li.

and I must be ros noetic so I tried to install ubuntu20.04.

after installation is complete, no found wifi.

and I install kernel 5.12.5. but I still don't found wifi and bluetooth.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide. Cheers!

Comment: You may want to look at [the Faustus project](https://github.com/hackbnw/faustus) on GitHub which offers support for various devices for Asus TUF.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/640544/problems-with-acer-nitro-5-an515-45-r715-in-ubuntu-21-04/p1?new=1

Comment: I try to install kernel 5.12.9 on ubuntu 20.04. because i need ros noetic.
and I run "sudo systemctl start bluetooth"
but wifi and bluetooth is not working. however i can check module with "lsmod" commend. Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: @sml My Wi-Fi did not work on Ubuntu even after I upgrade the kernel to 5.12. On Ubuntu 21, however, at least Wi-Fi worked after I upgraded the kernel from 5.11 to 5.12. (I am struggling with ASUS TUF F17 latop...)

Answer (score 0):

I had to update the kernel to version 5.16.9 to get Wifi, Bluetooth and the touchpad working.